# Should I set https on every page?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am bulding a marketplace which store users session ect.... I just added a SSL encryption for login and for the payment (I am using stripe as a payment gateway). I have seen sites like facebook forcing HTTPS on every page so that got me wondering, should I force HTTPS on every page or just on login and payment? 
side note, apparently SSL encrypted pages load faster

Comment: I think this has been asked before...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495570/to-use-or-not-to-use-ssl-why-use-ssl-always

Comment: and here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899088/how-important-is-it-to-use-ssl-on-every-page-of-your-website

Comment: those two questions do not totally answer my questions, I consulted them before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.** But not just because it loads faster, [or even ranks better on Google than non-HTTPS](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html) sites, but mainly because of security. Having HTTPS makes it harder to do a man-in-the-middle attack, whereby an attack intercepts the connection between your website and the user to either steal or modify data. The trouble with HTTP is that it is possible for someone to do exactly that, and then modify the links to point to a fake login page to steal data (this souunds paranoid but it happens).

While many pages use a script to check if the user is attempting to access HTTP and then redirect them to a HTTPS version, this might still be an issue for websites as attackers can still 'strip' out any HTTPS links (known as the [SSLStrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/) attack) to use only HTTP and then view the data, take a look at enabling [HSTS](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2014/02/websites-hsts) (HTTP Strict Transport Security) for enhanced security to avoid that. This is done by forcing browsers to only interact with the website on HTTPS connections and avoid any sort of downgrade attack.